# Entity Framework: Add item using Include

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables:

`User(id,name,birthday)`

and

`Teacher(id,id_user,post,specialization)`

`(Teacher : User)`

How To add Teacher using Include?

Something like that: `_db.Users.Include("Teacher").Add(teacher);`

Comment: Is the relationship between Teacher and User one to one?

Comment: Umm... I really don't see how `Include` could help here, it's only used for eager loading. When adding a new entry, you have to add the object to appropriate entity set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include is used to "eager-load" data, not to save. 
If you want to save a new Teacher and a new User object, it'll be something like this:

```
var t = new Teacher();
t.User = new User();
context.Teachers.Add(t)
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If EF is set to have Teacher as a derived class from User, you only need to create a `new Teacher()`, as the teacher is automatically a `User`. If they're set up as associated tables rather than inheritance, your answer is correct.

Comment: If i write `var t = new Teacher();
context.Teachers.Add(t)
context.SaveChanges();` as @Flater said, i add only fields from table Teacher or fields from User+Teacher?

Comment: If you've configured inheritance, **every** row in table `Teachers` will have a corresponding row in `Users`. Which makes sense, since `Teachers` have all the properties `Users` have (and some others too, obviously). You'll also notice that the ID in the `Teachers` table is the same ID as is used in the `Users` table (for the same object).

Comment: ok, thank you) And if i want to select teacher with fields User+Teacher using linq, i need create some other class like DTO class?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you've defined your models, if you got a navigation property for teacher within the user class , something like this:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //....
    public User User {get;set;} 
}
```

you should then be able to do

```
var teacher = new Teacher(){ User = someuser};
_db.Teacher.Add(teacher);
```

This will save both the teacher AND the user.